# Como evitar que se repita el mismo valor en una consulta SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Tengo una consulta a mi base de datos SQLite, la cual me devuelve una descripción de un articulo (Ej: Cocacola) y un precio.

Lo que me gustaria es que en vez de que me devuelva cada linea con el articulo y su precio, me devuelva el articulo que se repite, la cantidad de veces que se repite y un sumatorio del precio.

Ejemplo:

Cocacola, 20, 1,50x20.

Se que para el precio tengo que usar un SUM() pero para que solo me de la descripción una única vez no se como poder hacerlo y que me de la cantidad de veces que se repite en la consulta.

Un saludo.

Comment: Cuando realices preguntas puedes agregar lo que hayas tratado, de esta forma ayudas a la comunidad si alguien trata de realizar lo mismo que tu, saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No sé si te he entendido bien, pero creo que lo que buscas es:

```
SELECT NombreArticulo, COUNT(NombreArticulo) AS Cantidad, PrecioUnidad * COUNT(NombreArticulo) AS Total FROM Articulos GROUP BY NombreArticulo, PrecioUnidad
```

De todas formas, creo que sería mejor la consulta cogiendo únicamente el precio **unitario** y la **cantidad**, y después en `Android` hacer la multiplicación del total.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no soy muy experto en bases de datos y creo que esto es justo lo que necesito.